# Angular struggling with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having some issues with ng-repeat when I only have one item.

here is some partial code in my controller:

```
Data.get('company').then(function(data){
        $scope.subDomains = data;
    });
```

here is my html before the code is run:

```
<div id="subdomains">
    <ul>
        <li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains">{{sub.subdomain}} : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

here is my html after the code is run: (notice only one li has a subdomain) thus I only want to show one li

```
<div id="subdomains">
<ul>
<!-- ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->

<li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->

<li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains" class="ng-binding ng-scope">jason : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->

<li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->

<li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->

<li style="margin: 5px;" ng-repeat="sub in subDomains" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> : <button type="button" class="btn btn-mav" ng-click="removeAccount(sub.subdomain);">Remove</button></li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: sub in subDomains -->
</ul>
</div>
```

here is the console log:

```
Object {apiversion: "2", data: Object, event: Object, func: "listsubdomains", module: "SubDomain"}
    apiversion:"2"
    data:Object
      basedir:"public_html"
      dir:"/home/XXXXX/public_html"
      domain:"jason.XXXXX.com"
      domainkey:"jason_XXXXX.com"
      reldir:"home:public_html"
      rootdomain:"XXXXX.com"
      status:"not redirected"
      subdomain:"jason"
```

I am trying to list only the subdomains. When I have more than one it works perfectly but if I only have one I get the results I posted.

Comment: Your backend is returning an object when there's only one result and an array of objects when there are multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
Data.get('company').then(function(data){
    if(angular.isArray(data))
        $scope.subDomains = data;
    else
        $scope.subDomains = [data];

});
```

hope this help

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ng-repat="sub in subDomains"` and *subDomains* is an *object*, then you will have one repeat for every `object member`. Be sure that your *subDomains* is always an *array*, even if just one or none items exists.